# flutter - use json data

Tags: json, flutter

i'm new to flutter/ prgramming generally and currently struggeling with the usage of my json data. 
I already got a json file including my data and dart models (which were kindly provided to me).

Full JSON file: https://pastebin.com/utpKhnYx

Models: https://pastebin.com/gmfgLdR1

Now my problem: I want to display different titles or ids of my data in a test screen (for example as appBar title). I'm already printing the name of the first item in the terminal. But i dont know how to display this name in a widget. I guess i just need to pass the loaded data to my build method...

If you have any good source where i can learn things about this topic, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Test Screen:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../models/bone.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/test';

  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {


  Future<String> loadDataFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/api/data.json');
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    String jsonString = await loadDataFromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Bone bone = Bone.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print('Name ${bone.bones[0].name}');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("test")),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is simpler than it appears. You just want to pass your loaded data from the JSON to your widget?

Comment: Yeah i think so ... for example: I just want to be my appBar title the name which i printed in the console. I dont know how to pass it properly... i tried several approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've declared Bone object on class level.In initState our future method will read json file and store all the Data in Bone object.In our UI in appBar we can have a condition to show bone name **bone!=null** will check if our bone object has data.If it has data means **Bone.fromJson(jsonResponse)** has been assigned so we will show bone name in appBar else we will just assign any string so that our Text widget does't have null value in it else it will cause an error.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../models/bone.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/test';

  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {

  Bone bone;

  Future<String> loadDataFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/api/data.json');
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    String jsonString = await loadDataFromAssets();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    bone = Bone.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print('Name ${bone.bones[0].name}');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text( bone!=null ? bone.bones[0].name :"test")),
    );
  }
}
```